# Chain multiple method calls and wait until all are finished in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Say I had the following method call to make:

```
[[[[Foo init] addString:@"one"] addString:@"one"] addString:@"three"]
```

Where Foo contains:

```
@implementation Foo {
  NSString *string;
}

- (void)addString:(NSString *)text {
  string = [string stringByAppendingString:text];
}
```

Say I wanted to wait until all the `addString` methods were completed and wanted to print "onetwothree", but I had no idea how many times `addString` was going to be called. How would I achieve this? I tried to do this using `dispatch_group` as in:

```
@implementation Foo {
  NSString *string;
}

- (id)init {
  // setup
  [self complete];
  string = @"";
}

- (void)addString:(NSString *)text {
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^ {
      string = [string stringByAppendingString:text];
      NSLog(@"%@", text);
   }
}

- (void)complete {
  dispatch_group_notify(group,queue, 0), ^ {
    NSLog(@"Final String: %@", string);
  });
}
```

But this prints:

One
Final String: 
Two
Three

Any idea how I can get this done?

Comment: why not to use simple loop?

Comment: What would the stopping condition be?

Comment: Loop thru array with words you want to concat, on exit output the resulting string

Comment: The issue with that here is that I don't have an event to ping the loop to start iterating over the words.

Comment: ckeck my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use async processing you can do it this way:

```
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo {
    NSString *_string;
    dispatch_group_t _group;
    dispatch_queue_t _queue;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _string = @"";
        _group = dispatch_group_create();
        _queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addStrings:(NSArray *)strings {
    dispatch_group_async(_group, _queue, ^() {
        NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString new];

        for (NSString *str in strings) {
            [result appendString:str];
        }

        _string = [result copy];

    });
}

- (void)complete {
    dispatch_group_notify(_group, _queue, ^ {
        NSLog(@"Final String: %@", _string);
    });
}
```

Call this way:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
[foo addStrings:@[@"one", @"two", @"three"]];
[foo complete];
```